# How to get RoleId using Role Name in liferay?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

Is there any method where I can get the RoleId using Role Name? I have created some custom roles on my portal, like "Project Manager", "Client" and "Delivery Head". Now I need to get the respective role of these custom roles programmatically using Role Name.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `RoleLocalServiceUtil.getRole(companyId, name)` method to get the role object (instance of `RoleModel`). If you need the id, call `role.getRoleId()`.

Company id can be obtained by calling `ThemeDisplay.getCompanyId()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public long getRoleIdByName(String roleName) throws Exception {
    if (roleName != null && !roleName.isEmpty()) {
        for (Role role : RoleLocalServiceUtil.getRoles(0, RoleLocalServiceUtil.getRolesCount())) {
            if (role.getName().equals(roleName)) {
                return role.getRoleId();
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```